# no such file or directory in workdir

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to wrap my node express backend with Docker. However, when running my docker-compose file. I encountered error when running `npm install` stage throughout the dockerfile, saying it doesnt found the package.json copied in my local directory to the directory inside my container. Below is my project directory structure. Trying to proxy my node express backend API using nginx. Any sources that can help what I'm trying to achieve much appreciated.

error log:

```
> [4/5] RUN npm install:
#8 0.697 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#8 0.697 npm ERR! syscall open
#8 0.697 npm ERR! path /app/package.json
#8 0.698 npm ERR! errno -2
#8 0.699 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
```

project dir:

```
express-backend
 ├── docker
 |   ├── nginx
 |   |   ├── nginx.conf
 |   |   └── dockerfile
 |   └── dockerfile
 ├── src
 |   ├── model
 |   |   └── model.ts
 |   ├── controller
 |   |   └── controller.ts
 |   ├── middleware
 |   |   └── middleware.ts
 |   └── server.ts
 | .dockerignore
 | .gitignore
 | docker-compose.yml
 | package-lock.json
 | package.json
 | tsconfig.json
```

docker/dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 5000

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "/app/build/server.js", "npm run start"]
```

docker/nginx/dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

docker/nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name nodeserver;

        location / {
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  express:
    container_name: express_container
    build:
      context: ./docker
    environment:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  nginx: 
    container_name: nginx_container
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the context:

```
context: ./docker
```

So when you run

```
COPY . ./
```

You are copying files from that context, which doesn't include the `package.json`. You could specify the Dockerfile:

```yaml
  express:
    container_name: express_container
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    environment:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

But I'd suggest restructuring the folders to keep each image separate where that makes sense.

Comment: If I still keep the docker compose context as what it is using ```./docker``` so if im processing this right, in my dockerfile i should just changed the directory one level like ```../package.json ./``` and ```../ ./``` right?

Comment: So I moved the dockerfile for my express backend to my root dir instead and changed the context to ```./``` it has no problem installing the dependencies. I just want to know why changing dir one level didnt work in the dockerfile.

Comment: thank you for your advice regarding restructuring the folders to keep each image separately. I understand why now after processing what you said. Thanks man.

Comment: You can't copy files that aren't in the context. A copy from .. would be outside of the context.